# Не видны изменения в базе данных. При отладке изменения видны. Почему это происходит и как сделать так, чтобы изменения были видны всегда?

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-core, отладка

В моём приложении имеется действие AddFriend, в котором я добавляю одного пользователя в список друзей другого пользователя, обновляю данные в базе данных и сохраняю изменения, но позже изменения не видны.

Используемая модель:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SocialNetwork.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Sex { get; set; }

        public List<UserModel> Friends { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Класс HomeController (добавление пользователя в друзья в действии AddFriend, в который передаю id пользователя, которого хочу добавить в друзья):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SocialNetwork.Models;

namespace SocialNetwork.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        SocialNetworkContext db;
        public HomeController(SocialNetworkContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{user.Id}");
        }

        public IActionResult UserProfile(int Id)
        {
            ViewBag.is_auth_user = IsAuthorizedUser(Id);
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == Id);
            return View(user);
        }

        public IActionResult AddFriend(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            var new_friend = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == Id);
            if (user.Friends == null)
            {
                user.Friends = new List<UserModel>();
            }
            user.Friends.Add(new_friend);
            db.Users.Update(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{new_friend.Id}");
        }

        public IActionResult Users()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
            return View(user);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit(UserModel user)
        {
            db.Users.Update(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect($"~/Home/UserProfile/{user.Id}");
        }

        protected bool IsAuthorizedUser(int Id)
        {
            var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Name == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            if (user.Id == Id)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляю двух пользователей (залогинен под us2):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перехожу на страницу пользователя us1 и добавлю его в друзья:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе обратно на мою страницу список друзей по-прежнему пустой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при отладке (как показано ниже), если я зайду в мою базу данных, перейду в  список с друзьями текущего пользователя, окажется что он вовсе не пустой и они будут отображаться (если не зайти в базу данных пользователи отображаться не будут):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я так понимаю, они в базу записывают и там постоянно остаються, просто не выводяться на страницу?

Comment: @FX_Sektor Не совсем, при вызове одного действия они есть, при вызове другого - нет. К примеру - когда я запускаю действие AddFriend (добавляю в друзья), то у пользователя (user в коде), к которому я хочу добавить друга уже есть друг (это в случае, когда я запускал действие AddFriend до этого). Но когда я потом перехожу на страницу моего пользователя, к которому я уже добавил друга (происходит вызов действия Index, потом идёт переадресация на действие UserProfile), тут уже список с друзьями (List<UserModel> Friends) оказывается равен null.

Comment: Когда вы из метода Index вызываете метод UserProfile то у вас контекст, db который вы инициализируете при запуске контроллера обнуляется, походу в этом проблема?

Comment: И еще, вы уверены что метод UserProfile принимает не null id? Тут либо контекст db обнуляется, либо в метод UserProfile приходит null

Comment: @FX_Sektor В метод UserProfile передаётся id, с этим всё ок. А как db может обнулятся и где? И есть так, как это исправить?

Comment: Вы когда ставите точку остановы то она срабатывает один раз, когда в первый раз заходити в какой-то метод в этом контроллере? Дальше ж вы все действия делаете внутри этого контроллера? Сколько раз срабатывает точка остановы и когда на контексе? как у вас на скрине

Comment: @FX_Sektor У действий без переадресации - 1 раз, с переадресацией - 2 раза. То есть у Index, AddFriend - 2 раза, у UserProfile, Users - 1 раз.

Comment: @FX_Sektor как выяснилось значение user меняется после того как я заглянул в базу данных: https://ibb.co/XxHKHTs (все скрины делал в один и тот же момент, то есть на "Продолжить" не нажимал)

Comment: На "db = context" отрабатывает всегда, вместо со строчкой ниже - "}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это проблема отложенной загрузки в EF. Сущности не загружаются, пока я не получу к ним доступ. Нужно использовать `Include("Friends")` при загрузке пользователя в методе `UserProfile()`. Это будет гарантировать что связанные объекты будут загружены.

То есть нужно заменить эту строку: `var user = db.Users.First(u => u.Id == Id);`

На эту: `var user = db.Users.Include("Friends").First(u => u.Id == Id);`